# Is 'none' one of basic types in Lua?

Tags: lua

The basic types defined in Lua as below :

```
/*
** basic types
*/
#define LUA_TNONE       (-1)
#define LUA_TNIL        0
#define LUA_TBOOLEAN        1
#define LUA_TLIGHTUSERDATA  2
#define LUA_TNUMBER     3
#define LUA_TSTRING     4
#define LUA_TTABLE      5
#define LUA_TFUNCTION       6
#define LUA_TUSERDATA       7
#define LUA_TTHREAD     8
#define LUA_NUMTAGS     9
```

As Lua Document says that there only `8` basic types in Lua. However, there gets `10`. I know `LUA_TLIGHTUSERDATA` and `LUA_TUSERDATA` could finnally represented as `userdata`, but what about `LUA_TNONE`? And what is the differences of `none` and `nil`?

Comment: No. It not a type. It is only for use with C API.

Comment: I realize that `none` carries no value and its type tag is set to `LUA_TNIL`, but `nil` could carry value at the field of `value_`. Is it right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was already mentioned in the comments, `none` is used in the C API to check whether there is *no* value. Consider the following script:

```
function foo(arg)
    print(arg)
end

foo(nil) --> nil
foo()    --> nil
```

In Lua you can use `select('#', ...)` to get the number of parameters passed to `foo` and using C API you can check if the user supplied *no* argument at all (using `lua_isnone`). Consider the following small C library, which works like `type`, except that it can recognize, if no argument was given:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <lua.h>
#include <lauxlib.h>

static int which_type(lua_State* L)
{
    // at first, we start with the check for no argument
    // if this is false, there has to be at least one argument
    if(lua_isnone(L, 1))
    {
        puts("none");
    }
    // now iterate through all arguments and print their type
    int n = lua_gettop(L);
    for(int i = 1; i <= n; ++i)
    {
        if(lua_isboolean(L, i))
        {
            puts("boolean");
        }
        else if(lua_istable(L, i))
        {
            puts("table");
        }
        else if(lua_isstring(L, i) && !lua_isnumber(L, i))
        {
            puts("string");
        }
        else if(lua_isnumber(L, i))
        {
            puts("number");
        }
        else if(lua_isfunction(L, i))
        {
            puts("function");
        }
        else if(lua_isnil(L, i))
        {
            puts("nil");
        }
        else if(lua_isthread(L, i))
        {
            puts("thread");
        }
        else if(lua_isuserdata(L, i))
        {
            puts("userdata");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}

static const struct luaL_Reg testclib_functions[] = {
    { "type", which_type },
    { NULL,  NULL         }
};

int luaopen_testclib(lua_State* L)
{
    luaL_newlib(L, testclib_functions);

    return 1;
}
```

Compile this with something like `gcc -shared -fPIC -o testclib.so testclib.c`. In lua, we now load the library and use the function `type`:

```
local p = require "testclib"

p.type(nil)    --> nil
p.type({})     --> table
p.type("foo")) --> string
-- now call it without any arguments
p.type())      --> none, not nil
--type()       -- error: bad argument #1 to 'type' (value expected)
```

Note that you can't get 'none' and someother type from one call (while it is possible to receive multiple types by using multiple arguments, e.g. `p.type("foo", 42)`). This is quite logical, since it would be a syntactic error to use something like this:

```
p.type(, 42) -- error
```

One use of this can be seen in the `print` function, where `print(something)` prints the value (even it is not valid, e.g. `nil`), where `print()` prints a newline.

Comment: you can use `...` to distinguish `nil` and `none`  `function foo(...) if select('#', ...) == 0 then print 'NONE' else print((...)) end end`

Comment: Thanks, i did not know that. :)